# php mail() not sending Cc and Bcc

Tags: php, email

I have a php file which sends an email after a contact form has been submitted.

The email delivers correctly to the recipient, but it does never deliver to the Cc and Bcc. In the received email, anyways, the Cc is there(of course Bcc doesnt show up but if Cc is there Bcc should be too), but it just does not deliver to them.

Here is the code

```
<?php
$from = 'xx@xxx.com';
$to = $_POST['mail'];
$name = $_POST['nombre'];
$lastname = $_POST['apellido'];
$msg = "this is the content of the mail";
$subject = 'this is the subj';
$headers = "From:".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc:".$from.", xxx@xxx.com,xxy@xxy.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC:xyx@xyx.com\r\n";
if ($name=="" || $lastname=="" || $_POST['mensaje']=="" || $to==""){
    echo '0';
}else{
    if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)){
      echo '1';
    }else{
      echo '-1';
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: did you check your mail server's logs to see what happens after PHP handed over the email? And if you're generating other than "hi mom!"-type emails, you really should use something better than `mail()` - e.g. phpmailer or swiftmailer.

Comment: ....or a self-addressed stamped envelope. *Ah, the days of The Pony Express*.

Comment: I always know you where a _Cowboy Developer_ Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Got that straight Smokey* ;-) @RiggsFolly

Comment: @MarcB I have read several times I should use something other than `mail()`. Why? `mail()` works fine enough in all my sites. Even when sending html emails it works fine, with just adding some headers.

Comment: because mail is very very basic. once you start getting into messing with headers, or doing stuff like mime messages, it's FAR easier to use a proper mailer package, which will also offer far better diagnostics. mail() just returns true/false, which is essentially useless for debugging.

Comment: @MarcB As to this , I don't have access to the server logs, still I already asked my hosting provider to assist me with this. Anyways I started this question in case the mistake was in my code